# Bind ng-Model to hashMap

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Is there anyway to bind an input to `hashMap`?
I have Map Iwant to bind input to Map.I tried it to update the map from the controller by `this.Map.set(myInput)="myInput"`, but it didn't work.

Comment: post more code, and check browser for any error ?